# In R how to match and extract specific word from the text, irrespective of the formation?

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have the following sample text and I want to extract only **Machine Learning** from the text.

```
text <- c("Machine Learning is my fav topic.", "I love machinelearning.")

ifelse((found <- regexpr("\\sMachine Learning", text, 
                     perl =TRUE)) !=-1, substring(text, found, 
                          found+attr(found,"match.length")), "nothing found")
```

But it is returning me..

```
"nothing found" "nothing found"
```

I must get result as:

```
"Machine Learning", "machinelearning"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `(?i)` makes the regex case insensitive.  Use the pattern 'Machine' followed by zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by 'Learning'

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(text, "(?i)Machine\\s*Learning"))
#[1] "Machine Learning" "machinelearning"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 points, please see below:

1) When you want to search for both phrase you mention, you should use the expression as "machine\s?learning".   The ? after \s will ignore the space.

2) Use regexpr to find the match then use regmatches() function to extract the text.

```
> text <- c("Machine Learning is my fav topic.", "I love machinelearning.")
> m <- regexpr("machine\\s?learning", text, perl=TRUE,  ignore.case = TRUE)
> regmatches (text, m)

[1] "Machine Learning" "machinelearning"
```